# Laravel Artisan Serve cannot detect mysql when using Mamp

Tags: laravel, mamp

Sometimes I can't run `php artisan migrate` if I'm using mamp. It yield this error:

> [PDOException]    SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Can you add any more information on when you see this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you have to exclusively tell Laravel where the unix_socket location. In case of Mamp, you should add this line to your mysql config:

```
'unix_socket'   => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

If you are using xampp, the location would be `C:/xampp/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.

To get path to your active socket file, try login to your mysql server and run `status` command.